# Resize copied image on upload as thumbnail

Tags: php, upload, resize

I am working on an uploader and slowly getting it working, I am uploading 3 images at once, and setting arrays for each one as keys, with an increment of ++1.  I am wanting to resize the image before it gets copied to the thumbnail folder.

I have this code.

Everything works with it.
As you see, I started on getting the file info, but after that I am totally stuck on what to do after to resize the image proportionally with a maximum width of **x**px and height to match it without looking distorted.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank You.

EDIT --- I started working on it myself and wondering if this is the right approach to what i am doing.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['addpart'])) {

    $image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $name  = $_POST['username'];
    $i     = 0;
    foreach ($image as $key) {

        $fileData   = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]));
        $fileName[] = $name . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
        move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . end($fileName));
        copy("image/" . end($fileName), "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName));  


         // START -- THE RESIZER THAT IS BEING WORKED ON 
        $source  = "image_thumb/" . end($fileName);
        $dest    = "image_thumb/" . end($fileName);
        $quality = 100;
        $scale   = 1 / 2;

        $imsize = getimagesize($source);
        $x      = $scale * $imsize[0];
        $y      = $scale * $imsize[1];

        $im    = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        $newim = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
        imagecopyresampled($newim, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y, $imsize[0], $imsize[1]);
        imagejpeg($newim, $dest, $quality);
        // END -- THE RESIZER THAT IS BEING WORKED ON 
        $i++;
    }
    echo 'Uploaded<br>';
    echo 'Main Image - ' . $fileName[0] . '<br>';
    echo 'Extra Image 1 - ' . $fileName[1] . '<br>';
    echo 'Extra Image 2 - ' . $fileName[2] . '<br>';
    echo '<hr>';

}
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

1. Create input image object using [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) for example: `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i]))`

   It's the simplest way.

   Another option is to detect file type and use functions like `imagecreatefromjpeg ()`, `imagecreatefrompng()`, etc.
2. Create output empty image using [imagecreate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php)
3. Use [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) or [imagecopyresized()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) to resize image and copy+paste it from input image to output image
4. Save output image using function like [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)
5. Clean memory using [imagedestroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php)

Comment: @PeterSmith Would you able to guide me throught it as I am building it little by little

Answer (score 0):

The built-in image manipulation commands of PHP makes your code difficult to understand and to maintain. I suggest you to use a library which wraps it into a more productive way.

If you use [Intervention/image](https://github.com/Intervention/image), for example, your code will look like this:

```
<?php
// target file to manipulate
$filename = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];

// create image instance
$img = Image::make($filename);

// resize to width, height
$img->resize(320, 240);

// save it!
$img->save('thumbs/'. uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Read the full documentation here: http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads

Comment: Thanks you so much for that, i finished up my code and it scales the image based on a set width.